# Laravel 7 Eloquent relationships not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Im am using laravel 7. I have 2 tables, products and testimonials. Each testimonial is related to a product. So i made an 2 relationships:

- Product: hasMany('App\Models\OM\Testimonial');
- Testimonial: belongsTo('App\Models\OM\Product', 'product_id')

But when i dd(Testimonial->with('product)) i get this

> array:1 [▼   "testimonials" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
>   {#347 ▼
>       #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#358 ▶}
>       #model: App\Models\OM\Testimonial {#359 ▼
>         #table: "om_testimonials"
>         #fillable: array:4 [▶]
>         #connection: null
>         #primaryKey: "id"
>         #keyType: "int"
>         +incrementing: true
>         #with: []
>         #withCount: []
>         #perPage: 15
>         +exists: false
>         +wasRecentlyCreated: false
>         #attributes: []
>         #original: []
>         #changes: []
>         #casts: []
>         #classCastCache: []
>         #dates: []
>         #dateFormat: null
>         #appends: []
>         #dispatchesEvents: []
>         #observables: []
>         #relations: []
>         #touches: []
>         +timestamps: true
>         #hidden: []
>         #visible: []
>         #guarded: array:1 [▶]
>       }
>       #eagerLoad: array:1 [▶]
>       #localMacros: []
>       #onDelete: null
>       #passthru: array:19 [▶]
>       #scopes: []
>       #removedScopes: []   } ]

Comment: `Testimonial::with('product')->get();` this would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal, `with` asks Eloquent for eager-loading your relationship but it does not retrieve it yet because it allows you to add constraints on your "query". You need to do this to retrieve your models and their relationship

```php
Testimonial::with('product')->get();
```

You should also check the documentation, every detail is here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Well that's so stupid of me :))). I was missing de ->get(). Thank you!